# IIS 7 URLRewrite module REDIRECT fails, but REWRITE works for regex tripple period match

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, iis-7

Trying to get an IIS 7 URL Rewrite module rule to redirect instead of rewrite, but it does not appear to work.

This  rule works:

```
<rule name="lotsOfDots" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(\.\.\.+)(.*)" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="/Error/NotFound?{R:1}{R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

But if changed to a *Redirect* it does not, it goes to a 404 page (which is correct the url doesn't exist),

```
<rule name="lotsOfDots" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(\.\.\.+)(.*)" />
<action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/Error/NotFound?{R:1}{R:2}"/>
</rule>
```

Changing the redirect Url to "/" doesn't alter the outcome either.

Any suggestions?